# For a call option, what is the real-world probability of expiring in-the-money?

Tags: black-scholes, martingale

In the Black-Scholes world, the risk-neutral probability of expiring in-the-money is given by N(d2). Can I just replace the risk-free rate by the drift rate to obtain real world probabilities? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

If you know what the drift is.